# PHP Returning References

Tags: php, return-by-reference

> **Returning by reference is useful when
>   you want to use a function to find to
>   which variable a reference should be
>   bound**. Do not use return-by-reference
>   to increase performance. The engine
>   will automatically optimize this on
>   its own. Only return references when
>   you have a valid technical reason to
>   do so.

whats does the bolded mean?

does it refer to something like

```
public function &getHellos() {
    $sql = 'SELECT id, greeting FROM #__hello';
    $data = $this->_getList($sql);
    return $data;
}
```

where i am not binding to any variable?

Answer (score 4):

We return by reference when we want the function `GetRef()` to decide which variable, `$foo` or `$bar`, the reference `$foo_or_bar` should be bound:

```
$foo = "foo";
$bar = "bar";
function &GetRef(){
    global $foo, $bar;
    if(rand(0, 1) === 1){
        return $foo;
    }else{
        return $bar;
    }
}
$foo_or_bar =& GetRef();
$foo_or_bar = 'some other value';

var_dump($foo); // either one of this will be 'some other value'
var_dump($bar); // either one of this will be 'some other value'
```

Derick Ethans also elaborated on this in ["References in PHP: An In-Depth Look"](http://derickrethans.nl/talks/phparch-php-variables-article.pdf):

> This [returning by reference] is useful, for example, if you want to
>   select a variable for modification with a function, such as selecting
>   an array element or a node in a tree structure.

Example code demonstrating selecting array element via return-by-reference:

```
function &SelectArrayElement(&$array, $key){
    return $array[$key];
}

$array = array(0, 1, 2);
$element =& SelectArrayElement($array, 0);
$element = 10;
var_dump($array); // array(10, 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Na. You can't pass a reference to a function name.
When passing a variable by reference, if you change it's value in your function, it's value will also be changed outside of the function.

For example :

```
function test(&$var) {
    $var = strtolower($var);
}

function second_test($var) {
    $var = strtolower($var);
}

$var = 'PHP';

second_test($var);
echo $var;

echo "\r\n";

test($var);
echo $var;
```

This will display :

```
PHP
php
```

As the second_test method doesn't have the variable passed by reference, it's updated value is only updated inside the function.
But the test method as the variable passed by reference. So it's value will be updated inside and outside of this function.

Comment: @dmathieu You can in fact use byref in front of a function. It's perfectly legal PHP. Although since the introduction of PHP5, it's been discouraged.

Comment: Well providing a deprecated technique isn't what I'd call a good advice ;)

Comment: It's not deprecated in any way. Also, its use is only discouraged in situations where an object is being returned by reference, because in PHP5 it's done by default.

Comment: It was used in PHP 4 as a hack to work around shortcomings of the engine. In PHP 5 this isn't needed. That leaves very few (if any) legal cases for using it, but it's not deprecated per se.

Comment: @all, thanks for your replies. but i still want to ask: if i am not returning a class variable, in this case just a function variable, am i right to say i shld not use this (return by reference) because its already done by the engine?

Comment: The variables by reference should be used to return multiple variables in one single function.
So if you have only one variable to return, you don't need them.

Comment: but in the example shown http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php, it returns only 1 variable

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's referring to byref *arguments* not *functions*. For example this:

```
function doStuff(&$value1, &$value2) {
    ...
}
```

is an acceptable use of byref because the doStuff() function has to return 2 values. If it only doStuff() only needed to affect one value, it would be more elegant to have the function return it, by value, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The bolded part means it's useful if you want to keep a reference to a variable, instead of the value of this variable.

The example about [returning references](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php), on php.net, explains it pretty well, IMO.